# Apache reverse Proxy in Plesk 12 (for ASP.Net Core)

Tags: apache, proxy, asp.net-core, plesk

At the moment I try to get running a ASP.Net Core Application on my server. This server runs Debian 8, Apache 2 and Plesk 12. The Application runs at port 5000 and I wanted to add a reverse proxy to a specific subdomain to make the application available outside.

I have created a subdomain and added additional configuration as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyErrorOverride Off
ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
```

When using this, I only get an error of the server when browsing stating

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.

I searched Stackoverflow, ASP.Net Core documentation and other forums, which actually state to use my config (or a subset of this). Installing nginx is not an option because of other projects running on this server.

Do you have an idea what I am missing?

Thanks for your help!